# 4 Tables Joining in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some preps/views which im using in my final select clause in the following way :

```
select .......

from gr
full outer join go
on gr.ART_CONC=go.ART_CONC and 
gr.pt=go.pt and 
gr.p_act=go.p_act and 
gr.month_id=go.month_id and 
gr.art_desc=go.art_desc
```

Now i want to also include the following in my select clause, but im confused how the syntax and join would really go

```
sim ab join prep1

on ab.fp_num3 = article_num AND 
substr(ab.fp_num2,-2,2) = substr(pt10,-2,2)


where fp_data_kind='SEC PFE_ND_GO'
and fp_data_valid_from between to_date(:par_date_from, 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') and to_date(:par_date_to, 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Note : sim, prep1,gr and go are 4 tables/preps that already exist. 
Thanks in Advance !

Comment: are the joins all the same?

Comment: Let me explain more clearly..

I want to achieve a query for which the conditions are given below : 


1. There are 4 tables tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4 and there is a join condition between
i.  tab1.a and tab2.b
ii.  tab3.c and tab4.d

where a,b,c,d are columns in tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4 respectively


2. A join between tab1 and tab2 has to be a full outer join
3. Join between tab3 and tab4 has to be an inner join.
4. A where clause to filter records based on tab1.a = 'something'

How can i achieve it through SQL Query ?

Answer (score 0):

In this, table1/2/3/4 are your tables. `join_val's` are the values you are joining on. I did not fully understand your question or what you wanted so this one way to go about doing 4 joins.

```
select t1.something1
            ,t1.something2
            ,t1.something3
            ,t2.something1
            ,t2.something2
            ,t2.something3
            ,t3.something1
            ,t3.something2
            ,t3.something3
            ,t4.something1
            ,t4.something2
            ,t4.something3
from table1 t1
full outer join table2 t2
    on t1.join_val = t2.join_val
    ......
full outer join table3 t3
    on t1.join_val = t3.join_val
    ......
full outer join table4 t4
    on t.join_val = t3.join_val
```

Comment: Let me explain more clearly.. I want to achieve a query for which the conditions are given below : 1. There are 4 tables tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4 and there is a join condition between i. tab1.a and tab2.b ii. tab3.c and tab4.d where a,b,c,d are columns in tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4 respectively 2. A join between tab1 and tab2 has to be a full outer join 3. Join between tab3 and tab4 has to be an inner join. 4. A where clause to filter records based on tab1.a = 'something' How can i achieve it through SQL Query ?

Comment: @KapilLehar so you want a full outer join on tables 1&2, and an inner join on tables 3&4. How do you want to join the results of those those two joins?

Comment: There isnt a join between those 2 joins and that why the confusion. Is it possible to do it this way ? I'm a naive in sql joins

Comment: @KapilLehar I am confused again. you have described two separate joins. a full outer (group 1) and an inner (group 2) between two groups of tables but without a way to combine the two groups. So it sounds like you dont need tables 3&4 since you are never connecting them to tab1 (the thing you are filtering on.) I suggest you edit your question and write out a few example rows from table and then give a few rows for an example of what you want the query to output using the rows from the tables you wrote out.